# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'laravel'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.8

I am getting this error while trying to save an object into DB.

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'laravel' (SQL: insert into `cards` (`card_price`, `active`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (0, 1, 2019-10-10 15:14:43, 2019-10-10 15:14:43))

**.env**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=cardgame
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=P@assword1!
```

**Database.php**

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_T_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
```

**CardController.php**

```
  public function generateCards()
  {
  $card = new Card();
  $card->card_price = 0;
  $card->active = 1;
  $card->save();
  }
```

**Web.php**

```
 Route::get('/generate-cards', 'CardController@generateCards');
```

**Card.php**

```
class Card extends Model
{
 protected  $guarded =[];
}
```

**Migration file**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('cards', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('card_price');
        $table->integer('active');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

I've tried **clearing cache** and also have edited `DB_PASSWORD` To `DB_T_PASSWORD` as this corrected a similar issue earlier. Double checked the **DB name**, **passwords** etc & also other projects are already running also. I'm not able to figure it out.

Comment: show us the Card model and also run `php artisan config:cache` command

Comment: Have you tried to change `database` key by `cardgame` directly to `Database.php ` file ?

Comment: @pr1nc3 php artisan config:cache did the job. Thank you

Comment: @Goms No, but forge will anyway take the same value, right?

Comment: Glad i helped. Posted a full answer of the steps to take when you want to create a new database from scratch and migrate your tables. It could come handy for other users as well.

Comment: @pr1nc3 Yes for sure! It helped!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Go to your localhost server and drop the database and recreate a new one named **cardgame**
2. Go to your laravel project in console and run `php artisan config:cache` command. That way all your env variables will be used.
3. Run `php artisan:migrate` to run your migrations for your database and create your tables.

If you do the above 3 steps in that order you should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

You must clear the cache because your old configuration is in the cache file, just run this command in your terminal for clear cache:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by 2 simple step.

**Step:1** `php artisan config:cache`

**step:2** `php artisan migrate`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it following these steps:

**1)** Stop the server

**2)** Run `php artisan config:clear` .This command line will remove
*bootstrap\cache\config.php*  file

**3)** Start the server and It should work fine now

Answer (score 0):

create database in php admin then migrate your database again
php artisan migrate , it's work  100%

Answer (score 0):

I was also experiencing the same error and implemented all the solutions mentioned above but the error kept reoccuring. But I edited the.env and env.example file where the database = "laravel" to the name of my project for instance transport system and it worked. The best solution to the problem is editing both .env and env.example files with the name of your database that you created .